# Add date to redirected file name in windows powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

There must be a solution already here, but I can't find it ... what I'd like to do:

Make a link on the windows desktop, double clicking this link will execute a batch.bat and outputs something on stdout and stderr, I'd like to have the output on the console and also in a logfile.

For this part I ended with something like this:

```
powershell.exe -NoExit C:\mypath\mybatch.bat | tee 2>&1 mylog.log
```

This does what I want, but I'd like to have the log file named something like `mylog-20160317-2125.log`

I know that in powershell there's something like `[datetime]::now.tostring("yyyyMMdd-HHmm")` and `Get-Date -f yyyyMMdd-HHmm`

But how can I put one or another in my command line above to get the wanted log file name?

Thanks for any help ...

Comment: Are you sure you want -NoExit on your command?  Not enough context to tell if that is intended or not...

Comment: @KoryGill yes, I don't want the console close on end of the batch.bat - therefore the -NoExit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use something like:

```
powershell.exe -NoExit C:\mypath\mybatch.bat | tee 2>&1 "mylog-$(Get-Date -f yyyMMdd-HHmm).log"
```

Comment: perfect, exactly what I wanted and needed